# I am using Jquery Social feed. I am getting alert box from another site. how to disable that alert from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, facebook-social-plugins

Here is the alert box. I want to disable this alert box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(window).load(function() {
                var param = document.URL.split('#')[1];
                if( param != 'www.abc.com' ){
                alert('Here is msg');
            }
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: remove the `alert('Here is msg');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply overwrite `alert` with your own, empty, function.

```
window.alert = function() {};
```

Integrating it with your code :

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var param = document.URL.split('#')[1];
  if (param != 'www.abc.com') {
    alert('Here is msg');
  }

});
window.alert = function() {};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```